# Projection of the unit normal to the graph of function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define $\nu= \dfrac{Du}{\sqrt{1+|Du|^2}}$, where $Du$ is the gradient of $u$.

What $\nu$ rapresents? My book says that is the projection of unit normal to the graph, but the gradient in the expression of $\nu$ make me confused.Furthermore, what is the direction of unit normal to the graph in this context?

Comment: Isn't it a confusion between the gradient of a function defined in a cartesian way $y=f(x)$ with gradient $\binom{-f'(x)}{1}$ vs. defined in an implicit way $u(x,y)=0$ ?

Comment: You mean that i can see the function $u=u(x)$ as levels set of a function $U=U(u,x)$? What can I conclude in this way?